# Remove words that occur only once and with low IDF in R

Tags: r, nlp, data-cleaning, tf-idf, word-frequency

I have a dataframe with a column with some text in it. I want to do three data pre-processing steps:

1) remove words that occur only once
2) remove words with low inverse document frequency (IDF) and 3) remove words that occur most frequently

This is an example of the data:

```
head(stormfront_data$stormfront_self_content)

Output:

[1] "        , ,    stormfront!  thread       members  post  introduction,     \".\"     stumbled   white networking site,    reading & decided  register  account,      largest networking site     white brothers,  sisters!    read : : guidelines  posting - stormfront introduction  stormfront - stormfront  main board consists   forums,  -forums   : newslinks & articles - stormfront ideology  philosophy - stormfront activism - stormfront       network   local level: local  regional - stormfront international - stormfront  ,  .  addition   main board   supply  social groups    utilized  networking.  final note:      steps    sustaining member,  core member      site online,   affords  additional online features. sf: shopping cart   stormfront!"
[2] "bonjour      warm  brother !   forward  speaking     !"                                                                                                                      
[3] " check   time  time   forums.      frequently    moved  columbia   distinctly  numbered.    groups  gatherings         "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[4] "  !  site  pretty nice.    amount  news articles.  main concern   moment  islamification."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[5] " , discovered  site   weeks ago.  finally decided  join   found  article  wanted  share  .   proud   race   long time    idea  site    people  shared  views existed."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[6] "  white brothers,  names jay      member   years,        bit  info    ?    stormfront meet ups     ? stay strong guys    jay, uk"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am not too familiar with R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach with `tidytext`

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
word_count <- tibble(document = seq(1,nrow(data)), text = data) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  count(document, word, sort = TRUE)

total_count <- tibble(document = seq(1,nrow(data)), text = data) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  group_by(word) %>% 
  summarize(total = n()) 

words <- left_join(word_count,total_count)

words %>%
  bind_tf_idf(word, document, n)
# A tibble: 111 x 7
   document word             n total     tf   idf tf_idf
      <int> <chr>        <int> <int>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1        1 stormfront      10    11 0.139  1.10  0.153 
 2        1 networking       3     3 0.0417 1.79  0.0747
 3        1 site             3     6 0.0417 0.693 0.0289
 4        1 board            2     2 0.0278 1.79  0.0498
 5        1 forums           2     3 0.0278 1.10  0.0305
 6        1 introduction     2     2 0.0278 1.79  0.0498
 7        1 local            2     2 0.0278 1.79  0.0498
 8        1 main             2     3 0.0278 1.10  0.0305
 9        1 member           2     3 0.0278 1.10  0.0305
10        1 online           2     2 0.0278 1.79  0.0498
# … with 101 more rows
```

From here it is trivial to filter with `dplyr::filter`, but since you don't define any specific criteria other than "only once", I'll leave that to you.

**Data**

```
data <- structure(c("        , ,    stormfront!  thread       members  post  introduction,     \".\"     stumbled   white networking site,    reading & decided  register  account,      largest networking site     white brothers,  sisters!    read : : guidelines  posting - stormfront introduction  stormfront - stormfront  main board consists   forums,  -forums   : newslinks & articles - stormfront ideology  philosophy - stormfront activism - stormfront       network   local level: local  regional - stormfront international - stormfront  ,  .  addition   main board   supply  social groups    utilized  networking.  final note:      steps    sustaining member,  core member      site online,   affords  additional online features. sf: shopping cart   stormfront!", 
"bonjour      warm  brother !   forward  speaking     !", " check   time  time   forums.      frequently    moved  columbia   distinctly  numbered.    groups  gatherings         ", 
"  !  site  pretty nice.    amount  news articles.  main concern   moment  islamification.", 
" , discovered  site   weeks ago.  finally decided  join   found  article  wanted  share  .   proud   race   long time    idea  site    people  shared  views existed.", 
"  white brothers,  names jay      member   years,        bit  info    ?    stormfront meet ups     ? stay strong guys    jay, uk"
), .Dim = c(6L, 1L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution to Q1 in several steps:

Step 1: clean data by removing anything that is not alphanumeric (`\\W`):

```
data2 <- trimws(paste0(gsub("\\W+", " ", data), collapse = ""))
```

Step 2: Make a sorted frequency list of the words:

```
fw <- as.data.frame(sort(table(strsplit(data2, "\\s{1,}")), decreasing = T))
```

Step 3: define a pattern to match (namely all the words that occur only once), make sure you wrap them into boundary position markers (`\\b`) so that only exact matches get matched (e.g., `network`but not `networking`):

```
pattern <- paste0("\\b(", paste0(fw$Var1[fw$Freq==1], collapse = "|"), ")\\b")
```

Step 4: remove matched words:

```
data3 <- gsub(pattern, "", data2)
```

Step 5: clean up by removing superfluous spaces:

```
data4 <- trimws(gsub("\\s{1,}", " ", data3))
```

Result:

```
[1] "stormfront introduction white networking site decided networking site white brothers stormfront introduction stormfront stormfront main board forums forums articles stormfront stormfront stormfront local local stormfront stormfront main board groups networking member member site online online stormfront time time forums groups site articles main site decided time site white brothers jay member stormfront jay"
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Remove double spacing and punctuation at the start of strings: 
# cleaned_str => character vector
cstr <- trimws(gsub("\\s*[[:punct:]]+", "", trimws(gsub('\\s+|^\\s*[[:punct:]]+|"',
                    ' ', df), "both")), "both")

# Calulate the document frequency: document_freq => data.frame
document_freq <- data.frame(table(unlist(sapply(cstr, function(x){
  unique(unlist(strsplit(x, "[^a-z]+")))}))))

# Store the inverse document frequency as a vector: idf => double vector: 
document_freq$idf <- log(length(cstr)/document_freq$Freq)

# For each record remove terms that occur only once, occur the maximum number 
# of times a word occurs in the dataset, or words with a "low" idf: 
# pp_records => character vector
pp_records <- do.call("rbind", lapply(cstr, function(x){
    # Store the term and corresponding term frequency as a data.frame: tf_dataf => data.frame
    tf_dataf <- data.frame(table(as.character(na.omit(gsub("^$", NA_character_, 
                                                           unlist(strsplit(x, "[^a-z]+")))))),
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    # Store a vector containing each term's idf: idf => double vector
    tf_dataf$idf <- document_freq$idf[match(tf_dataf$Var1, document_freq$Var1)]

    # Explicitly return the ppd vector: .GlobalEnv() => character vector
    return(
      data.frame(
        cleaned_record = x,
        pp_records =
          paste0(unique(unlist(
            strsplit(gsub("\\s+", " ",
                          trimws(
                            gsub(paste0(tf_dataf$Var1[tf_dataf$Freq == 1 |
                                                        tf_dataf$idf < (quantile(tf_dataf$idf, .25) - (1.5 * IQR(tf_dataf$idf))) |
                                                        tf_dataf$Freq == max(tf_dataf$Freq)],
                                        collapse = "|"), "", x), "both"
                          )), "\\s")
          )), collapse = " "),
        row.names = NULL,
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )
    )
  }
))

# Column bind cleaned strings with the original records: ppd_cleaned_df => data.frame 
ppd_cleaned_df <- cbind(orig_record = df, pp_records)

# Output to console: ppd_cleaned_df => stdout (console)
ppd_cleaned_df
```